# mixing strings and variables in ruby output

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm doing a codecademy tutorial to learn about Twitter's api. It requires us to print the response according to the following instructions

```
# ADD CODE TO PRINT THE TWEET IN "<screen name> - <text>" FORMAT
```

The following is saying that, although I'm parsing the response correctly, I'm not generating the correct output.

```
def print_tweet(tweet)
  user = tweet["user"]["name"]  
  text = tweet["text"]
  puts user + '-' + text

end
```

I'm so used to using instance variables in Rails that I'm not confident about simple Ruby like this.  How should I write the function to generate output in this format?

```
"<screen name> - <text>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to add spaces around the `-` in your output. It should read

```
puts user + ' - ' + text
```

Answer (score 6):

Prefer string interpolation instead of string concatenation:

Replace: `puts user + '-' + text`

With:

```
puts "#{user} - #{text}"
```